# Integrating github projects in my app using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, github

I am developing my first app in android and I need some custom controls. So I want to know if I can use any github project in my app directly? If so then do I have have add any copyright or license information in my app anywhere? Also I want to know how I can use this below project in my app?

https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

https://github.com/mutualmobile/CardStackUI

Note: The app which i am developing will be released as a commercial app

Thanks in advance,

IamHuM

Comment: Welcome @iamhum on StackOverflow. Yes, you can use the library by adding **gradle** dependence in **build.gradle** of android project.

Answer (score 0):

[`CircleImageView`](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) readme, and [`CardStackUI`](https://github.com/mutualmobile/CardStackUI) readme both mention the right Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.mutualmobile.android:cardstack:0.5.2'
}
```

That fits the [Android basic project setup](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Basic-Project-Setup):

> The most simple Android project has the following build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.1.0"
}
```

Add your own dependencies to your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you looked at the README file carefully, you will find this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
}
```

That basically tells you how to install the library.

Go to your build.gradle file (Note that there are two of them, go to the one that says "Module: app"). Scroll to the very bottom and you'll see something like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.+'
}
```

Yours might be slightly different, but you get the idea :)

Now add the line you found in the README to here, so it becomes:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.+'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0' // this line!
}
```

Now do a gradle sync by pressing [image] on the top!

Just do the same thing with the other library!

Answer (score 0):

You have the IDE answers above :) Regarding licences - any commercial app complies with licences, you must understand the licences of the projects you use, and give the appropriate credit accordingly, github projects are usually Apache 2, which **in a nutshell** means that you can use it freely, but must:

1. include a copy of the licence (Apache 2)
2. formally mention the usage of any third-party library you are using by name and by the licence it complies to.

Other licences have other meanings and some might even be unwanted - there are some licences that you would **ABSOLUTELY NOT** want to use on a client app, but can be used on server side mechanisms.

Read about BSD, GPL, LGPL, and when in doubt - seek legal help (make sure they specialize in exactly that - licencing).

The place to do it could be inside the setting.
(e.g. have a look at the facebook app, inside app settings->terms & policies->More Resources->Third Party Notices), or, depending on the nature of your app - even outside, if you need the user to agree to terms of service or anything else.
In a lot of apps this would usually mean a webview directing to a webpage with all the info, since it's a lot to put in your app and would bloat it.

Check under LICENCE.txt or in the README.txt that are published with the projects.

For more info, refer to [The StackExchange OpenSource resources](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/).

Remember - you are liable, and yes - that means someone can sue if you do not handle this properly.

**"open source is free speech, not free beer"** :) 
good luck!